# Click a button and paste into cursor position | Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, copy, paste

I am creating a small app that when I press ctrl+C copies the selected text and inserts it into a button in my window. What I want to do now is to click on this button and paste the text inside the cursor.

For example, let's suppose I have a button with the text inside "Attention please", and I am writing an e-mail, I want to click on it, and the app paste "Attention please" in my e-mail.

I am using Python | PyQt5 for that. Here is y code:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSize

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 400))    
        self.setWindowTitle("CopyToClipboard")
        self.btn = QPushButton()
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.step = 10

        QApplication.clipboard().dataChanged.connect(self.clipboardChanged)

    def clipboardChanged(self):
        text = QApplication.clipboard().text()
        self.btn = QPushButton(text,self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.pasteFunction(self.btn.text()))
        self.btn.setMinimumHeight(80)
        self.btn.setMaximumWidth(270)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)
        self.show()
        self.step = self.step + 100

    def pasteFunction(self, texto):
      print(texto)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = Window()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Comment: if you want to copy text and paste text from clipboard use pyperclip module

Comment: Are you trying to create a clipboard manager? If yes, that won't work like this, for these important reasons: 1. right now your program accepts focus, and as soon as it gets focus (which happens as soon as you click on it), there is absolutely ***no way*** to know what other window *previously* had focus and eventually "paste" on it; 2. to work with the OS clipboard, you must access [QClipboard](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html); 3. Qt is not able to "force" pasting on external programs, so you need to use system libraries that do so; be aware that not all systems/programs would allow this.

Comment: Hi @musicamante, this is exactly what I am trying to do, a clipboard manager. Considering your answer, is there any other language that I could use to develop this application? Thanks you in advance